# Oracle: how do I take a Job offline from PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, jobs, dbms-job

I need to look for a JOB by thw WHAT column. 
Check if it is actually running. If not take it offline and put online again to make it start immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming based on the column names you referenced that you are using the `DBMS_JOB` package to schedule your jobs rather than the newer and more sophisticated `DBMS_SCHEDULER`, it's not obvious to me that you really need to take the job offline.  If you want to force it to run immediately,

```
dbms_job.run( <<job number>> );
```

If you really do want to take the job offline, you can break it

```
dbms_job.broken( <<job number>>, true );
commit;
```

and then you can unbreak it

```
dbms_job.broken( <<job number>>, false );
commit;
```

You can determine whether the job is currently running by querying the `DBA_JOBS_RUNNING` view

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM dba_jobs_running
 WHERE job = <<job number>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Toad go to schema browser and look for jobs. rt clk on the job and make it offline and then commit it. This is the easy way if you don't remember commands.

Comment: This question is not about Toad and it's not clear at all how this answer relates to the question

Comment: yes its not about toad but to take a job offline and if he was using toad that is the easy way